# Conditional expectation of an uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with $U_1$ distributed uniformly on the interval $(-1, 1)$. Compute $\mathbb{E}(U_1 + \ldots + U_n |\max(U_1, \ldots, U_n) = t)$ for $t \in (-1, 1)$.

So my attempt was to try to compute $\mathbb{E}(U_1 |\max(U_1, \ldots, U_n) = t)$, writing $U_1 = U_1 1_{\{U_1 < t\}} + U_1 1_{\{U_1 \geq t\}}$ but I do not think this is a right approach. Generally speaking, in my opinion I do not feel intuitively the conditional expectation in a satisfactory way and hence my problems with this question, I guess.

Comment: One step might be to consider the distribution of $\max(U_1,\ldots, U_n)$.

Comment: The condition tells you that there exists one variable with value $t$, and each of the other $n-1$ independent random variables are at most equal to $t$. What is the expected value of $U_{i}$ given that $U_{i} \le t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $i=1,\ldots,n$, we have, using the [Total Law of Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), conditioning on the value of $U_i$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \\
E(U_i\vert \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t) &=& E(U_i\vert U_i=t\cap \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t)P(U_i=t\vert \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t) \\
&& + E(U_i\vert U_i\neq t\cap \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t)P(U_i\neq t\vert \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t) \\
&& \\
&=& t\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}\; + \;\dfrac{t+1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{n-1}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

By the linearity of expectation,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(U_1+\cdots+U_n\mid \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t) &=& \sum_{i=1}^n{E(U_i\mid \max\{U_1,..,U_n\}=t)} \\
&& \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n{\left(t\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}\; + \;\dfrac{t+1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)} \\
&& \\
&=& t + (n-1)\dfrac{t+1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Note:**

This result is intuitive: one value of $t$ and the remaining $n-1$ values taking the average value in interval $(-1,t)$.